# IDE or addons for IDE that support W3C WAI

Tags: eclipse, ide, accessibility, dreamweaver

Are there any IDEs or Addons for the main IDEs that support and actively highlight missing basic W3C WAI implementations.  Ideally it would look through my codebase and highlight issues such as  tags that are missing the alt="" text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jared - theres a plugin in development for netbeans called ACCESSIBLE which may do what yoyu are after I believe.  Have a looky here: http://www.accessible-eu.org/  NetBeans is pretty cool too.. http://netbeans.org/